Why SEARCH function is not returning partial matches?
I have a sheet with 2 columns. I'm using a filter formula to extract only fruits:



Type
Fruit




Orange
Yes


Apple
Yes


Cucumber
No



FILTER('Mapping List'!A2:A999,'Mapping List'!B2:B999="Yes")

Then, I'm adding | to it, in order to filter on multiple items:
TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER('Mapping List'!A2:A999,'Mapping List'!B2:B999="Yes"))

Now, I have a main sheet that looks like this:



Some data
Column B




data
Orange


data
Apple


data
Orange sweet


data
Apple sweet



My formula would need to say TRUE to all of the 4 items, since Orange or Apple are in the string.
ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Statement!B2:B999,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER('Mapping List'!A2:A999,'Mapping List'!B2:B999="Yes"))))

But it's only saying TRUE for the first 2, which means that for some reason the SEARCH function is not able to identify strings that are separated by a space/not able to find partial matches.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

You need to split each word of second table, second column then use search. Try-
=BYROW(B9:B12,LAMBDA(x,OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(x,," "),TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(A2:A4,B2:B4="Yes")))))))



Here is one way of doing this, which is more simpler to understand, and it doesn't require the usage of TEXTJOIN() function.


=MAP(E2:E6,LAMBDA(x, OR(1-ISERR(SEARCH(FILTER(A2:A4,B2:B4="Yes"),x)))))


